# GNUplot input filename as variable

Tags: bash, variables, gnuplot

I want to input the filename to GNUplot as a variable.
I've written a gnuplot script, which includes the following lines:

```
path="path/to/file"
plot "< cat $path | sed '1,4d'" using 1:2
```

When I run the script, the gnuplot window opens but there's nothing in it.
If I replace `$path` with the actual path, the graph is correctly plotted.

Please can you suggest a way of doing this?  Thank you.

Comment: Post your GNUplot command as well.

Comment: @konsolebox the `plot` line is a gnuplot command. What isn't yet clear is whether `path` is declared in bash or in gnuplot as it is a valid declaration in both languages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this to interpolate the value of the gnuplot variable in your command:

```
path="path/to/file"
plot "< cat ". path ." | sed '1,4d'" using 1:2
```

Note that it is not necessary to use `cat` and `sed` together:

```
path="path/to/file"
plot "<sed '1,4d' ". path using 1:2
```

Be careful with your spaces! You can use `print` instead of `plot` to see what command will be executed.

Sometimes, I like to use `sprintf` to do this kind of thing:

```
cmd = "1,4d"
plot sprintf("<sed '%s' %s", cmd, path) using 1:2
```

It's a bit longer but it's also clearer in my opinion.

By the way, in this particular case, you don't need to use any external tools at all. You could just do:

```
plot path using 1:2 every ::4
```

Which will skip the first 4 lines of your file.